# AttibuteError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'

Tags: python, flask, flask-httpauth

To set some context I'm creating an API through Flask. To authenticate users, I'm using 
[flask-HTTPAuth](https://flask-httpauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). As a part of accessing login protected resources, I've defined my `verify_password` callback in `auth.py`. If the user credentials provided evaluate to True, the user is attached to the `g` object.

In `app.py`, there is the route `/api/v1/users/token`, that when requested, a token is issued to a user that is logged in. However when I try to access `g.user` in `app.py`, I get the error: `AttributeError: '_AppCtxGlobals' object has no attribute 'user'`.

Why isn't there any existing 'user' attribute not while accessing the `g` object in `app.py`?

**auth.py**

```
from flask import g
from flask_http import HTTPBasicAuth

from models import User

basic_auth = HTTPBasicAuth()

@basic_auth.verify_password
def verify_password(username, password):
    try:
        api_user = User.get(User.username == username)
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        return False
    user_verified = api_user.check_password(password)
    if user_verified:
        g.user = api_user
        return True
    return False
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, g, jsonify

from auth import basic_auth as auth

app = Flask(__name__)

@auth.login_required
@app.route("/api/v1/users/token")
def issue_api_token():
    token = g.user.request_token()
    return jsonify({'token': token})
```

Answer (score 1):

The order of your decorators is wrong, `@app.route` should always be first.

```
@app.route("/api/v1/users/token")
@auth.login_required
def issue_api_token():
    # ...
```